# Stuctured XML to Map or Flat XML

Tags: xslt, mapping, mule

I need to insert the line items on my XML to a Map or a flat XML in mulesoft. Iam planning to use XSLT but Im having only single values instead of multiple Line Items. Im not sure how the for each function works for this. any help would be appreciated.

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><XmlInterchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1" xmlns="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/">
<InterchangeInfo>
    <Date>2016-02-29T05:56:10.272+05:00</Date>
    <XmlType>LightWeight</XmlType>
    <Source></Source>     
    <Target></Target>
</InterchangeInfo>
<Payload>
    <WhsDockets>
        <WhsDocket>
        <Identifier>                                     
        <Reference>2370519</Reference>
         </Identifier>
    <DocketDetail>
        <WarehouseCode>ROC</WarehouseCode>
        <CustomerReference>3340527</CustomerReference>
        <Units>41</Units>
        <Packages>0</Packages>
        <Pallets>0</Pallets>
        <Weight DimensionType="KG">720</Weight>
        <Cubic DimensionType="M3">5.922</Cubic>
        <TransportInsurance>0.0000</TransportInsurance>
        <ShipperCODAmount>0.0000</ShipperCODAmount>
        <CustomerOrderDetail>
            <OrderType>ORD</OrderType>
            <DateRequired>2015-09-02T00:00:00</DateRequired>
            <Consignee AddressType="CEA">
                <AddressLine1>Cnr Maroochydore and BroadmeadowRds</AddressLine1>
                <CityOrSuburb>MAROOCHYDORE</CityOrSuburb>
                <StateOrProvince>QLD</StateOrProvince>
                <PostCode>4558</PostCode>
                <CompanyName>Bunnings Maroochydore OLD Warehouse</CompanyName>
                <CountryCode>AU</CountryCode>
                <ContactName>The Import Manager</ContactName>
            </Consignee>
        </CustomerOrderDetail>
        <CustomAttributes />
    </DocketDetail>
    <DocketLines>
        <DocketLine>
            <Product>E4342</Product>
            <Description>R 3 5/3 6 175mm x 430mm x 1160mm</Description>
            <QuantityFromClientOrder>5</QuantityFromClientOrder>
            <QuantityActuallyOrdered>5</QuantityActuallyOrdered>
            <ProductUQ>MST</ProductUQ>
            <LineAttributes />
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <Confirmation>
                <Lines>
                    <Line>
                        <Quantity>25</Quantity>
                        <QuantityUQ>PAC</QuantityUQ>
                    </Line>
                </Lines>
                <Quantity>25</Quantity>
            </Confirmation>
        </DocketLine>
        <DocketLine>
            <Product>E2281</Product>
            <Description>R 3 5 175mm x 580mm x 1160mm</Description>
            <QuantityFromClientOrder>4</QuantityFromClientOrder>
            <QuantityActuallyOrdered>4</QuantityActuallyOrdered>
            <ProductUQ>MST</ProductUQ>
            <LineAttributes />
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <Confirmation>
                <Lines>
                    <Line>
                        <Quantity>16</Quantity>
                        <QuantityUQ>PAC</QuantityUQ>
                    </Line>
                </Lines>
                <Quantity>16</Quantity>
            </Confirmation>
        </DocketLine>
    </DocketLines>
   </WhsDocket>
</WhsDockets>
</Payload></XmlInterchange>
```

I need to flatten the XML but use the Litem Item details together with the Reference Number per each Item.

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Items>
    <LineItem>
        <Date/>
        <Order>2370519</Order>
        <Client>Bunnings Maroochydore OLD Warehouse</Client>
        <Product>E2281</Product>
        <Description>R 3 5 175mm x 580mm x 1160mm</Description>
        <Quantity>4</Quantity>
        <UOM>MST</UOM>
        <Warebouse>ROC</Warebouse>
        <Carrier>Deluxe</Carrier>
    </LineItem>
</Items>
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I used XSLT to transform it to the output file but I cannot produce the 2nd line item

Comment: is there a specific reason why you want to do it with XSLT Transform only? Have you considered DataWeave which may be easy to achieve expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at DataWeave to transform it from current xml to new xml?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-examples#xml-basic